# Saving Stream.Write to existing .CSV file doesn't replace data, only adds to existing data. How do I only replace the data?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, savefiledialog

The following code is used to save a CSV string, however, if I save to an existing .CSV, instead of replacing the data, it only adds the new string to the data already there.
How do I remedy this? Is it something inherent to how the Stream.Write function works, or is this an idiosyncrasy of Excel and .CSV?

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

dialog.AddExtension = true;
dialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.FilterIndex = 1;
dialog.Title = "Save As";
dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
dialog.CheckPathExists = true;
dialog.DefaultExt = ".csv";
dialog.ValidateNames = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName, true);
    myStream.Write(//Function which returns a CSV-formmatted string//);
    myStream.Close();
    OpenFile(dialog.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName, false);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.100%29

the second parameter (bool `append`), is well described :

> append
>       Type: System.Boolean
>       Determines whether data is to be appended to the file. If the file exists and append is false, the file is overwritten. If the file
>   exists and append is true, the data is appended to the file.
>   Otherwise, a new file is created.

Comment: Well, I feel a little silly for not looking at StreamWriter's definition first, but thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `append` to false, that way, `StreamWriter` will overwrite the file, rather than appending the data to it.

```
StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName, true)`  change `true` to `false`

Intellisence will tell you what your parameters are named as you type the function call, and it might give you a tooltip about what they mean.  You should pay attention to that

I believe that simply typing `new StreaWriter(dialog.FileName)`  will set append to false by default.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the proper parameter to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx):

```
new StreamWriter(
    path: path
    append: false);
```